# How to build a Docker container that starts a .jar and runs on a RaspberryPi 4B?

Tags: java, docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, armv7

I am working on a little application that I want to run in a docker container on a Raspberry Pi (Model 4B, 32Bit, 4GB RAM). I am learning Docker currently, so far I have only built and run stuff on my dev machine ( a mac). The container setup and jar work without problems on that machine.

This is my very basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /
ADD my_jar.jar my_jar.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar my_jar.jar
```

As you can see there is not much going on. I would like to just be able to `Docker build . -t myDockerImage` on the pi and then run my container. Building succeeds, according to the output, but running fails with an error:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

I did some research, and all I could find was the suggestion to use OpenJDK. Did that, but can't build, it says:

```
no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries
```

I looked around on Docker Hub, but it doesn't seem like there is an image for java that fits this architecture. Or maybe I don't know what to look for...?

**So how do I get java in a docker container onty this machine (preferrable in a fairly easy, convenient way, but if that doesn't exist, I am happy to do it the hard way, what ever that might entail)?**

Btw: This is what `lshw` states about the RPi:

```
raspberrypi
    description: ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
    product: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
    serial: 10000000b3320840
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp
```

Comment: You'd need to find or build an image with a ARM-compatible OS and a JRE/JDK for that. Maybe that one fits your needs: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/adoptopenjdk/

Comment: If we think that Raspberry  is a kind of server, the best practice is build he image in the build server not in the target server. If your problem continues, are you open to use a docker registry? https://i.ibb.co/YNGJ7bJ/minimal-docker-flow.png

Comment: Thank you @Robert for the `adoptopenjdk` link, that seems the most promising "easy" solution. Yet I still didn't get it to work. Running my image built with `FROM arm32v7/adoptopenjdk:8`fails stating `java: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
Also tried jdk 11 since that is the example on the page, which also doesn't work, but totally different error: `OpenJDK Server VM warning: No monotonic clock was available - timed services may be adversely affected if the time-of-day clock changes`...

Comment: nevermind, 'adoptopenjdk:15' works, which was actually the jdk version I used to build the jar with. Interestingly it doesn't seem to matter when building the image on the mac ...It still shows the clock warning, but that's fine with me for now

Comment: @Thomas, if your comment were an answer I would mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @michpohl that can be arranged ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the JRE still depends on the operating system and that depends on the platform architecture. The standard docker image for Java will most likely use a amd64/x64 based Linux OS with the appropriate JDK installed.

Raspberry PI, however, uses the ARM architecture, hence the output `ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)`.

So you need an ARM-compatible image such as one of those: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/adoptopenjdk

I'm not sure how compatible ARM v7 and v8 are so I'd suggest you stick to the v7 images :)

Comment: worked with latest `arm32v7/adoptopenjdk` with raspberry pi 3 B+ Java 16 was running

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's getting built for another platform, by default. Did you try passing `--platform=linux/arm/v7` while building the image?

See if [this](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1170) helps.

Comment: yes, tried it, to no avail. The linked issue is interesting, but I haven't figured out yet how the propsed solutions help  me here...

Comment: @michpokl it won't work, ok? the image is not there for raspberry. *BUT* there is another one that works ``adoptopenjdk/openjdk11``